# Grails deployment on production - manually db migration

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm coming from the world of python, django where usually our deployment flow was as follow:

1. tar/gz our code release
2. unpack on the production
3. Run db migration manually via south
4. Run the app

Grails is a little bit different than python/django mainly because the end product is a compiled war. My biggest problem is the manual DB migration. I don't want to run it automatically, one suggested solution that I saw is to use `dbm-update-sql` to generate manual sql file, but in order to produce it I need my local DB to have the same version as the production DB - I don't like it.

any other suggestions ? it looks to me like the only way to run it manually is to deploy yhe source code on the machine and run the `dbm` commands there.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `dbm-update-sql` against the production database, it won't make any changes since like all of the -sql scripts it's there to show you what would be done in the event of a real migration. To be safe, create a user that doesn't have permission to make any changes and use that when you run the script. Create a custom environment in `DataSource.groovy` with that user info and the production connection info and specify that environment when running the script.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend *not* deploying the source to your production systems. Since, you want to manually control your database migrations, outside of the normal flow of a Grails application I'd recommend you look at using [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) as a stand alone tool.

Obviously since you don't want to manage having a copy of your production schema to diff against this is going to be a lot of manual work for you (e.g. keeping your changes up to date).

The database migration plugin can be used to create sql scripts that you manually run, but you do need a production schema to diff against. I'd recommend you head this route, but you seem set against doing so.

Comment: The reason I prefer manual is error handling, what happens if the migration fails, I don't want the war to load at all, I want it to fail, in addition in case it fails I want clear error message and no go and search for it in catalina.out

Comment: I seem to recall if the migration fails the application will stop loading and thus won't deploy. Errors will appear in catalina.out in the case of Tomcat. Again, if you want to control this manually look at using Liquibase as a stand alone tool (it's what the database migration plugin uses internally).

Comment: Do you know which groovy dsl extension is being used? I found a possible candidate - https://github.com/tlberglund/groovy-liquibase but while reading http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1774 it looks like the plugin is implementing its own dsl parser. It looks like if I want to go manual then I'll have to use the xml representation, a real bummer.

Comment: You can look at the source of the plugin here: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to use Tim's DSL. I looked at it but it was incomplete (I haven't checked lately though) and there were a couple of issues that I'm forgetting now that made it incompatible with the plugin.